# Spring STS: How to automatically create a webpage for all API methods, like .Net does

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In .Net one creates a set of web API's and it comes with a webpage that just lists each API method and one can choose which to run.

What is the equivalent is Spring STS?

[Here's a picture of what I mean, .Net web api page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDQzY.png)

Comment: have a look to jhipster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Swagger UI for this which is very easy to set up with Spring using a few annotations.

Have a look at https://swagger.io/

And a guide for setting it up with Spring here:

http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

Comment: Nice!  And easy too.

Comment: Yeah it's a really neat little tool :)

Comment: Just FYI...this page gets directly to the core of the setup: http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

Comment: Ah yeah that's the same guide I originally followed when first using it. Should have linked that really. I'll add it to the answer for anyone else reading your question.